# How can I install Ubuntu with no boot options?

Tags: command-line, system-installation

Here is my walk if shame:  I ran the command

```
sudo rm -rf ~ /.local
```

And it deleted everything on my system.  It is (or was) a Vizio CT14.  The reason I ran this command in Terminal, if this is relevant, was to uninstall Ubuntu so I could reinstall a clean version.

The PSU is working, as evidence by the blue light and churning sound of the hard disk, though the screen doesn't come on.  Does this mean my graphics card has been deleted too?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you access tty1-6 (Ctrl+Alt+F2 or any other F key 1 - 6) ?

Comment: No, the system isn't responding to anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Just create a liveusb with ubuntu on it and install it from there. You just removed the files for ubuntu to run, you can still boot from other devices such as the usb key, or a dvd or whatever. Nothing shows up on presumably because there is nothing there.

Comment: I tried booting from a live USB and nothing happened.  I don't get a blank screen because the screen doesn't even power on

Comment: Nothing at all? Ouch. What happens when you plug in another screen?

Comment: I just tried to plug into my TV via HDMI.  The TV displayed a no-signal screen.  I verified that the cable and input were operable by using another laptop.

Comment: Well without a screen there's not much to do :/
Probably won't work but is this relevant? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: That didn't work either.  I think I may have been unclear about the black screen.  There's no power going to the screen.  It's not a black light.  Anyway, I followed the instruction, waiting a few seconds between each command, and nothing has happened

Comment: Better safe than sorry^^
Well I have no idea why the screen doesn't start. Maybe edit the question to make this problem more apparent, after that reinstalling the system is pretty forward I should think. And maybe add more details if you can?